# protected function within abstract and inheritted class

Tags: php

i have an abstract class which is extended another class and function is defined **protected** and again this function this inherited from another class and now i am trying to call that function.
It gives me error.I don't know what is wrong with me. My code looks like:

```
abstract class abc {
abstract protected function f1($name, $address);
}
class xyz extends abc {
protected function f1($name, $address) {
    return "$name , $address";
}
}
class jkl extends xyz {
   echo $this->f1('Ravi','Delhi');
}
```

Comment: `class jkl extends xyz {
   echo $this->f1('Ravi','Delhi');
}` is invalid..... code in a class should be in a method, but if you fix that, then [it will work](https://3v4l.org/3NKsr)

Answer (score 0):

To make your code working you should wrap the `echo` in class jkl in a public function.

```
<?php
abstract class abc {
    abstract protected function f1($name, $address);
}

class xyz extends abc {
    protected function f1($name, $address) {
        return "$name , $address";
    }
}

class jkl extends xyz {
    public function echodata(){
        return $this->f1('Ravi','Delhi');   
    }
}


echo (new jkl)->echodata();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put code to make a call to your protected method in the class definition, but not inside a method.  This isn't valid.  You will need to put it within a method:

```
class jkl extends xyz {
   public function go(){
     echo $this->f1('Ravi','Delhi');
   }
}
```

Then create an instance of that class and call the method on it from within your main program body:

```
$obj = new jkl;
$obj->go();
```

HTH